# GitHub Codespaces: how to set x86_64, AMD64, ARM64 platform?

Tags: docker, github, vscode-devcontainer, codespaces, github-codespaces

First, the question: **is there a way to choose the platform (e.g. x86_64, AMD64, ARM64) for a GitHub Codespace?**

Here's what I've found so far:

**Attempt 1 (not working):**

From within GitHub.com, you can choose the "machine" for a Codespace, but the only options are RAM and disk size.

**Attempt 2 (EDIT: not working):** `devcontainer.json`

When you create a Codespace, you can specify options by creating a top-level `.devcontainer` folder with two files: `devcontainer.json` and `Dockerfile`

Here you can customize runtimes, installed packages, etc., but the docs don't say anything about determining architecture...

...however, the VSCode docs for `devcontainer.json` has a `runArgs` option, which "accepts Docker CLI arguments"...

and the Docker CLI docs on --platform say you should be able to pass `--platform linux/amd64` or `--platform linux/arm64`, but...

When I tried this, the Codespace would just hang, never finishing building.

**Attempt 3 (in progress):** specify in `Dockerfile`

This route seems the most promising, but it's all new to me (containerization, codespaces, docker).  It's possible that Attempts 2 and 3 work in conjunction with one another.  At this point, though, there are too many new moving pieces, and I need outside help.

1. **Does GitHub Codespaces support this?**
2. **Would you pass it in the Dockerfile or devcontainer.json?  How?**
3. How would you verify this, anyway?  [Solved: `dpkg --print-architecture` or `uname -a`]
4. For Windows, presumably you'd need a license (I didn't see anything on GitHub about pre-licensed codespaces) -- but that might be out of scope for the question.

References:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/devcontainerjson-reference
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/
https://docs.docker.com/desktop/multi-arch/
https://docs.docker.com/buildx/working-with-buildx/

Comment: At last check, arm platforms aren't supported directly on GitHub, at most you can run it under an interpreter like qemu. https://github.community/t/ask-about-github-hosted-runners-arm64-platform-support/167483

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT: December 2021**

I received a response from GitHub support:

> The VM hosts for Codespaces are only x86_64 and we do not offer any ARM64 machines.

So for now, setting the platform does nothing, or fails.

But if they end up supporting multiple platforms, you should be able to (in Dockerfile)

`RUN --platform=arm64|amd64|x86-64 [image-name]`,

Which is working for me in the non-cloud version of Docker.

---

**Original answer:**

I may have answered my own question

In `Dockerfile`:

I had `RUN alpine`

changed to

`RUN --platform=linux/amd64 alpine`

or

`RUN --platform=linux/x86-64 alpine`

checked at the command line with

`uname -a` to print the architecture.

Still verifying, but seems promising.  **[EDIT: Nope]**

So, despite the above, I can only get GitHub codespaces to run x86-64.  Nevertheless, the above syntax seems correct.

**A clue:**

In the logs that appear while the codespace is building, I saw `target OS: x86`

Maybe GitHub just doesn't support other architectures yet.
Still investigating.

Answer (score 3):

Currently only x64 based hosts running Linux are supported for Codespaces. Other hardware and host is types are yet to be announced.

Comment: Could you link to the docs / article that states this?  I didn't see it.

Comment: There isn't any at the moment, as GitHub documents what it does support, not what isn't yet. At the moment Codespaces is hosted on x64 linux docker hosts. I've got it straight from the CodeSpaces team.